# Rails 4 permit nested hash with dynamic keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Facing issues in permitting nested hash with dynamic keys in params. I have referred other similar questions on stack overflow but no luck so far. Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is the error raised.

**ActionController::UnpermittedParameters** found unpermitted parameters: volunteers_slots_attributes, sign_up_slots_attributes

```
{"event"=>{
"name"=>"ss", 
"volunteers_slots_attributes"=>{
"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "needed_count"=>""},
"1"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "needed_count"=>""},
... 
}, 
"sign_up_slots_attributes"=>{
"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "title"=>"", "quantity"=>""}, 
"1"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "title"=>"", "quantity"=>""}, 
"2"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "title"=>"", "quantity"=>""},
 .... 
}, 
"supplies_note"=>""}}
```

Controller:

```
 def event_params
    params[:event].permit(:name,:supplies_note,
    :volunteers_slots_attributes,
    :sign_up_slots_attributes)
 end
```

Event Model:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sign_up_slots, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteers_slots, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your strong params like

```
params
  .require(:event)
  .permit(
    :name,
    :supplies_note,
    volunteers_slots_attributes: [
      :_destroy,
      :needed_count
    ],
    sign_up_slots_attributes: [
      :_destroy,
      :title,
      :quantity
    ]
  )
```

Comment: Yes I Tried... ArgumentError at /events '0' is not a valid repeat

Comment: The error does not make sense, would it be possible to send the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I found that problem is in Event model with enum field. (Migrating to rails 4). Your solution works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure the `event.rb` model file has accept nested attributes.

In your case it should contains some lines like those:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteers_slots, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sign_up_slots, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
# ...
```

Comment: Yes it contains accepts_nested_attributes_for.. I updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can always have something like `params[:event].permit(:name: volunteers_slots_attributes: ['0', '1'])` to permit nest attributes.

Comment: @Bemie Chiu I cannot hardcode  ['0', '1'] because it is dynamic.